# How to make mount point in Solaris 10(installing Oracle RAC)?

Tags: oracle, solaris-10, mount-point

I want to install Oracle RAC on solaris 10, using ASM but I am new in it...

So I want to mount /u0 directory on the disk volume **/dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2**

1) I have created /u0 directory by root user like this:

```
# mkdir /u0
```

2) I've added the following entries in .vsftab file:

```
 /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2   /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s2  /u0    ufs    2      yes    -
```

For to make file system to mount automatically.

3) Then I have typed the following command, for to mount directory now:

```
mount /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2 /u0
```

Am I right???? Please, give me some advice how to mount directory on solaris and what steps should I make for to install oracle RAC on this system.

P.S.
Step 3 gives me the following error:

```
mount: /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2 or /u0, no such file or directory
```

P.S2 
Which Oracle should I download for to install RAC?

Comment: I think you'll have more luck on serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ASM you don't need to create a filesystem  on the ASM disk.  The ASM itself will act as a filesystem for oracle.

With regards to RAC installation, you will need to configure a  shared storage between two or more servers  involved into the cluster.  If it is a proof of concept the easiest way will be to use NFS.

Please check the following guide on how to install ASM on NFS

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/UsingNFSWithASM.php

Alternatively you can install RAC using NFS as a shared storage without ASM.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/OracleDB11gR2RACInstallationOnLinuxUsingNFS.php

Best regards 
Yuri